# Customizing WordPress Header Navigation Menu on WordPress Premium Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been encountering a problem on my WordPress premium theme on its navigation menu on header. When it is clicked it will not redirect to the destined page. I have been working to fix it on Google Chrome element editor and finally solved the problem by editing some element on Google Chrome element editor.

Before

```
<li id="menu-item-2011" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1076 current_page_item menu-item-2011"><a href="http://stagjurnal.dev/">Home</a></li>
```

After

```
<li id="menu-item-2011" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1076 current_page_item menu-item-2011"><a href="http://stagjurnal.dev/" **onclick="location.replace('http://stagjurnal.dev/'),'_top'"**>Home</a></li>
```

My question is, I can't find the file where I have to edit and input my code as I am not familiar with WordPress file structure, and when I try to search for the id="menu-item-2011", on the project folder it can't be found for some reason.

I have tried to contact the developer of the theme but they don't even reply to my email, though I have tried to fix this myself. The theme is called Enigma (https://themeforest.net/item/enigma-minimal-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/18298127).

Comment: I would investigate why the link is not working instead of using JavaScript to change the location. If you do it with JavaScript you can't open the link in new tab for instance.

Comment: And your current code is not enough to reproduce the issue, I suggest you try to post a minimal code needed to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi all, the problem is i can't find the file location for the navigation bar, that's why this is the best that i can do. anyone of you have experience in customize wordpress theme ?

Comment: I understand your issue, but if the issue is the one you described your problem definitely is not that you can't find the right file. Setting the location with javascript is a bad idea and fixing the original problem would probably be simpler. Also because the theme is not free, not many can help you finding the right file.

Comment: Hi FINDarkside, thanks for the respond. Trust me i would make a better fix after i can find the file. This solution is just temporary as it is urgent for my company website.

Comment: Well I can't really help you with that, since I don't have the theme. The structure can be anything, since wordpress doesn't limit the way you structure themes. My guess is that there's some javascript preventing the link from working, and in that case you need to edit the javascript file. You could try disabling javascript and trying if the link works.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the header.php file, normally anything to do with the header should be in there.

Comment: Hi claymore, i already did that, but the navigation bar is not there.